# implementation error in Python recursive expression

Tags: python, recursion

I'm solving the problem.
You have to leave the last list, but the previous list is printed out again.

```
def merge(xs,ys):
  # xs, ys, ss = xs, ys, []
  xs, ys, ss = xs[:], ys[:], []
  while xs!=[] and ys!=[]:
    if xs[0] <= ys[0]:
      ss.append(xs[0])
      xs.remove(xs[0])
    else:
      ss.append(ys[0])
      ys.remove(ys[0])  
  ss.extend(xs)
  ss.extend(ys)
  return ss
```

---

```
accumulator = []
remain = []

def merge2R(xss):

    if len(xss)% 2 != 0 :
     OExcept = len(xss)-1 
     remain.append((xss[OExcept]))
     xss.remove(xss[OExcept])   
     

   
    if xss !=  []:           
     accumulator.append(merge(xss[0],xss[1]))
     xss.remove(xss[0])
     xss.remove(xss[0])   
     return merge2R(xss)

    else: 
     return accumulator + remain
```

The result comes out like this.
How can I fix it?

```py
>>> merge2R([[2],[1,3],[4,6,7],[5,8],[9]])
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]
```

Desired result value:

```py
>>> merge2R([[2],[1,3],[4,6,7],[5,8]])
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7,8]]
>>> merge2R([[2],[1,3],[4,6,7],[5,8],[9]])
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7,8], [9]]
```

Comment: how is `merge` defined?

Comment: I modified it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was working, you just needed to reset `accumulator` and `remain`

```py
def merge2R(xss):
    # Declare use of globals
    global remain
    global accumulator

    if len(xss) % 2 != 0:
        OExcept = len(xss)-1
        remain.append((xss[OExcept]))
        xss.remove(xss[OExcept])

    if xss != []:
        accumulator.append(merge(xss[0], xss[1]))
        xss.remove(xss[0])
        xss.remove(xss[0])
        return merge2R(xss)

    else:
        x = accumulator + remain
        # Must reset accumulator and remain
        accumulator = []
        remain = []
        return x
```

Because you initialise both arrays as empty, then append to them:

```py
# Remain
remain.append((xss[OExcept])) 
# Accumulator
accumulator.append(merge(xss[0], xss[1]))
```

After you have finished with the data in those arrays (at end of function) you need to discard it:

```py
accumulator = []
remain = []
```

---

The result of not discarding these arrays is evident when calling the function with the same argument multiple times:

```py
print(merge2R([[2], [1, 3]]))
print(merge2R([[2], [1, 3]]))
print(merge2R([[2], [1, 3]]))
print(merge2R([[2], [1, 3]]))
print(merge2R([[2], [1, 3]]))
```

```py
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Can you say that this code is recursive?

Comment: Yep, by definition a recursive algorithm must call itself and have a base case. You satisfy both.

Comment: Why do you reset the accumulator and the main at the end?

Comment: I'll add that to my answer